# Show Row Index in cells of a Column in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewlinkcolumn

I need to show an auto increment value in cells of a column in `DataGridView`. The type of column is `DataGridViewLinkColumn` and the grid should be like this:

```
| Column X | Column Y |
-----------------------
|    1     | ........ |
|    2     | ........ |
| ........ | ........ |
|    n     | ........ |
```

I tried these codes, but it doesn't work:

```
int i = 1;
foreach (DataGridViewLinkColumn row in dataGridView.Columns)
{                
    row.Text = i.ToString();
    i++;
}
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle [`CellFormatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx) event of your `DataGridView` and then provide the value for cell there:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex == this.dataGridView1.NewRowIndex)
        return;

    //Check if the event is fired for your specific column
    //I suppose LinkColumn is name of your link column
    //You can use e.ColumnIndex == 0 for example, if your link column is first column
    if (e.ColumnIndex == this.dataGridView1.Columns["LinkColumn"].Index)
    {
        e.Value = e.RowIndex + 1;
    }
}
```

It's better to not use a simple `for` or `foreach` loop because if you sort the grid using another column, the order of numbers in this column will be unordered.

Comment: Dear You Rock.Thanks for Help